# Como faço para "Contabilizar" os nós maiores de uma XML (XElement)

Tags: c#, xml

Opa, como vocês estão? Estou apreendendo C# por conta própria (depois de ser iniciado em programação em python na universidade).

Estou tentando criar 1 software que leia um arquivo XML e queria dividir o arquivo da mesma forma que a imagem a seguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso queria que "contasse" para cada nó maior "Customer". Para que futuramente caso eu queira imprimir o primeiro, segundo, terceiro. (Ficaria a escolha do usuário).

Bom estou tentando fazer isso usando "ArquivoXML".Descendent("Customer").

```
IEnumerable<XElement> items =
                 from el in pu2.Descendants("Customer")  
                 select el;
            foreach (XElement el in items)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (el.ToString());
            }
```

A questão é que estou tentando de todos os jeito transformar/adquirir os valores da variável (XElement) em INT, so que não consigo :(.

Queria saber se estou usando o "IEnumerable" Corretamente, se deveria usar "List". Já pensei em transformar em texto e usar "ReadallLines" para pegar os arquivo em string. Porém acredito que exista uma forma melhor de fazer isso.

Vi recentemente que talvez eu deva utilizar o ICollection ou IList.

Enfim quem puder me ajudar :) ou até poder falar um caminho, ou onde estou errando, ficaria extremamente agradecido.

Comment: Se deseja percorrer a coleção com base em um índice, use o bom e velho `for` e não `foreach`. Sobre `IEnumerable` x `IList`, não tenho certeza porque C# não é minha praia, pesquise o que representam cada um e escolha o mais adequado. `ICollection` não deve ser porque deve representar coleções que podem não ter necessariamente ordenação de primeiro item, segundo, terceiro, etc. como por exemplo conjuntos (_sets_) ou similares, que não têm ordem definida.

Comment: o que você quer dizer com contabilizar? `items.Count()` ???

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, exato, no caso eu queria que quando eu digitac no console: "1". Ele imprimi as informações do {1} (na imagem), e assim sucessivamente. Estou tentando usar o string[](transformando o xml em texto) (ou object) e tentando alocar cada node <Customer>. Só que to tentando dificuldade em fazer isso de forma automatizada.

Comment: Andei pesquisando acredito que o ideal serial usar ilist.item[int32], vou ver aqui mais sobre.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "forma automatizada"?